# Javascript - Toggle Visibility

Tags: javascript

I am trying to display a button when the input is valid. 
It doesn't work, it just displays all the buttons.
Here is the JavaScript:

```
        var toggleVisibility = function ()
        {
        hasOccurred = validate(textEntry);

            if (hasOccurred == false) {
            $("addBtn").style.visibility = "visible";
            $("deleteBtn").style.visibility = "hidden"; 
            }
          else if (hasOccurred == true) {
            $("addBtn").style.visibility = "hidden";
            $("deleteBtn").style.visibility = "visible"; 
            }
        }
```

This is the HTML for the buttons:

```
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="addBtn" oninput="toggleVisibility()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></i> Add to Array</button><br/>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" oninput="toggleVisibility()" id="deleteBtn"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></i> Delete from Array</button><br/>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="sumBtn">Sum of Array</button>
```

Comment: Are you using jQuery? If so classes have a dot  `$(".addBtn")` and you can just use `.hide()` and `.show()`. For example: `$(".addBtn").show()` other than `$(".addBtn").style.visibility = "visible"`.

Comment: I am not using jQuery.

Comment: Then what library are you using? `$("addBtn")` isn't native JavaScript.

Comment: If you use "$()" it means you should have jQuery librairy... Otherwise use document.getElementById("addBtn") instead of $("#addBtn")

Comment: I did `var $ = function (id) 
   {
    return document.getElementById(id); 
   }`

Answer (score 0):

You're using the $ as if you're using jQuery (but with incorrect CSS selectors). Without jQuery you need `document.getElementById("...")`

Note: I changed hasOccurred so that the snippet works.

```js
var toggleVisibility = function() {
  hasOccurred = false;

  if (hasOccurred == false) {
    document.getElementById("addBtn").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("deleteBtn").style.visibility = "hidden";
  } else if (hasOccurred == true) {
    document.getElementById("addBtn").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("deleteBtn").style.visibility = "visible";
  }
}

toggleVisibility();
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="addBtn" oninput="toggleVisibility()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></i> Add to Array</button>
<br/>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" oninput="toggleVisibility()" id="deleteBtn"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></i> Delete from Array</button>
<br/>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="sumBtn">Sum of Array</button>
```